# C++ inheritance with non-default constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

For a project I am looking at a case where the following situation exists. There is a class foo which requires an identifying number x when constructed. So its constructor argument looks something like foo(x).

Now I want to derive a class based on foo, called bar, which will basically hold two foo's internally and to the outside world acts as a single foo. The way I want to do this is by use of two constructor arguments y and z for bar, which will then, in the constructor, generate foo(y) and foo(z). I hope it's clear.

My current implementation looks something like:

```
class bar : public foo {
public:
    bar(int y, int z)
    {
        _foo_ptr_1 = foo::foo(y);
        _foo_ptr_2 = foo::foo(z);
    };

private:
    foo *_foo_ptr_1;
    foo *_foo_ptr_2;
};
```

Where foo is a class that is an already existing class looking something like:

```
class foo {
public:
    foo(int x) :
    _private_var(x) {
    };
};
```

Now, I know that since foo has no default constructor with zero arguments this will not work. I would prefer not to add a meaningless constructor with zero arguments to foo for several reasons. Is there a nice way to get this working? Right now my compiler (gcc under Ubuntu) gives me the following error:

> error::no matching function for call to foo::foo()

A quick attempt to try and work around this is by replacing the constructor of bar:

```
bar(int y, int z) : foo(y)
```

But this also does not work.

I have not been able to find a working solution for this yet online, and would be gratefull for any help.

Comment: `_foo_ptr_1 = foo::foo(y)` is _not_ how you construct classes in C++!

Comment: Are you sure you have `foo *_foo_ptr_1;` in your _real_ code? Where is this error message issued?

Comment: The error is issued at the line of the constructor of bar.

Comment: Since `bar` is a `foo` itself, are you sure you need additional __two__ `foo`s inside? Maybe __one__ additional `foo` would be enough?

Comment: Does `bar` need its own ID? in which case it should accept one as an argument. If it does not need an ID, why is it inheriting from `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
bar(int y, int z) : foo(y)
{
  _foo_ptr_1 = new foo(y);
  _foo_ptr_2 = new foo(z);
}
```

Please not that trying to invoke a class constructor directly like it was a static method is not how classes are constructed in C++. At the very least, you use `new classname(arguments)`, as above.

This is not really recommended however... explicit memory management using `new` and `delete` is easy to get wrong.

First, consider that you may not have to allocate any `foo` instances at all.. you can just have simple member variables:

```
class bar : public foo {
public:
  bar(int y, int z) : foo(y), _foo_1(y), _foo_2(z)
  {
  }

private:
  foo _foo_1;
  foo _foo_2;
};
```

If you *really* must construct new instances the hard way, you should consider using smart pointers such as `unique_ptr`.

```
class bar : public foo {
public:
  bar(int y, int z) : foo(y), _foo_ptr_1(new foo(y)), _foo_ptr_2(new foo(z))
  {
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<foo> _foo_ptr_1;
  std::unique_ptr<foo> _foo_ptr_2;
};
```

`unique_ptr` ensures that your resources are correctly deallocated when their owner is destroyed. If your `_foo` member variables don't belong exclusively to their parent `bar` instance, then you can use `shared_ptr` instead. It is well worth reading up on the use of these utility classes.

Comment: +1 for everyone that suggests not to use pointers when you can avoid them ;)

Comment: This seems to be working, at least for the trimmed down case, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are trying to work around the inheritance.

By deriving form `foo` you are saying that a `bar` is a `foo`. And a foo has a `_private_var`, so you have to fill this var with a meaningful value.

If you want to act in the same way as a `foo`, but not share its implementation, you want to share only an interface with `foo`. This is done in C++ by using a class with only pure virtual functions and a default  constructor. For instance call it `foo_interface`. This should then be implemented by `foo` (with a 'real' implementation) and by `bar` with an implementation to combines the results of two `foo`'s

Also you shoudl instantiate foo* in a different way:

```
   _foo_ptr_1 = foo::foo(y);
```

should be

```
   _foo_ptr_1 = new foo(y);
```

or even better, if you can, don't make foo a pointer. As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681932/137369